# Which SQL is best to use

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

i have a mysql database with about 60 Million records. i will have to generate report every day.

I have two type of sql statement.

**Method1**

```
SELECT TransferStatus as Transfer_Status, count(ID) as Count 
FROM calldetails 
WHERE YEAR(IVRStartTime) = '2015' AND MONTH(IVRStartTime) = '11' AND DAy(IVRStartTime)='05' AND CallTransfer LIKE '163%' 
GROUP BY TransferStatus;
```

**Method2**

```
SELECT TransferStatus as Transfer_Status,  
count(ID) as Count FROM  calldetails 
WHERE  (IVRStartTime BETWEEN '2015-11-05 00.00.00' AND '2015-11-05 23.59.59') 
AND CallTransfer LIKE '163%'  
GROUP BY TransferStatus
```

I tried both queries both takes approximately 15 minutes to give results. My question is which one is the best to use and is there any other way i can improve the performance.

Comment: hint: create an appropriate index.

Comment: The first one is not sargable. So even if you add an index on the date column it will still be slow. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable

Comment: Why closed?  This is not opinion-based, but fact-based.  Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `BETWEEN` best approach

```
SELECT TransferStatus as Transfer_Status,  
count(ID) as Count FROM  calldetails 
WHERE  (IVRStartTime BETWEEN '2015-11-05 00.00.00' AND '2015-11-05 23.59.59') 
AND CallTransfer LIKE '163%'  
GROUP BY TransferStatus
```

this one is best because `BETWEEN` perform fast as compare many where clause

or use `index` is always be a good habit because :-

A database `index` is a data structure that `improves` the `speed` of operations in a table. Indexes can be created using one or more columns, providing the basis for both rapid random lookups and `efficient` `ordering` of access to records.

Comment: Tnx. I created the index  and tested both sql statement. This one works well , it takes approximately 2 minutes where other one takes approximately 10 minutes to give results.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the DATE function to return the date part of your datetime value

```
SELECT TransferStatus as Transfer_Status,  
count(ID) as Count FROM  calldetails 
WHERE  DATE(IVRStartTime) = DATE('2015-11-05') 
AND CallTransfer LIKE '163%'  
GROUP BY TransferStatus
```

That will be more efficient for handling the date condition.

You need to use EXPLAIN to see what the execution plan is so that you can optimise it with indexes to speed up the query

Comment: No.  `DATE(IVRStartTime)` is not sargable, so it won't use an index on `IVRStartTime`.